# Finding parents in a tree hierarchy for a given child LINQ (lambda expression)

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have data with parent child relationships, finding all children for a given parent is straight forward using Linq, however I have problem other way around, finding all of parents when child is provided.

```
  List<FlatData> elements = new List<FlatData>
          {
   new FlatData {Id = 1, ParentId = NULL ,Text = "Apple"},
   new FlatData {Id = 2, ParentId = 1, Text = "Cat"},
   new FlatData {Id = 3, ParentId = 2, Text = "Dog"},
   new FlatData {Id = 4, ParentId = 3, Text = "Elephant"}
       };
```

When Id 4 is given I need to able to reverse traverse and find all parents using LINQ (lambda expression).

Comment: What do you mean "all parents"? Do you mean the parent and the parent of the parent...?

Comment: Yes, like if Id 4 is given, I should reverse traverse and get all elements : in this case for Id =4 its parents should be 3,2,1. Thank you

Comment: I am not sure if you can solve this issue with LINQ alone. You need some kind of recursion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use recursion to do something like this:

```
private IEnumerable<FlatData> FindAllParents(List<FlatData> all_data, FlatData child)
{
    var parent = all_data.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == child.ParentId);

    if (parent == null)
        return Enumerable.Empty<FlatData>();

    return new[] {parent}.Concat(FindAllParents(all_data, parent));
}
```

And use it like this:

```
int id = 4;

var child = elements.First(x => x.Id == id);

var parents = FindAllParents(elements, child).ToList();
```

This solution works, but if you have a large data set, then you should consider using a `Dictionary<int,FlatData>` to make it it faster to fetch a `FlatData` object given it's `Id`.

Here is how the method would look like in this case:

```
private IEnumerable<FlatData> FindAllParents(Dictionary<int,FlatData> all_data, FlatData child)
{
    if(!all_data.ContainsKey(child.ParentId))
        return Enumerable.Empty<FlatData>();

    var parent = all_data[child.ParentId];

    return new[] {parent}.Concat(FindAllParents(all_data, parent));
}
```

And here is how you would use it:

```
var dictionary = elements.ToDictionary(x => x.Id); //You need to do this only once to convert the list into a Dictionary

int id = 4;

var child = elements.First(x => x.Id == id);

var parents = FindAllParents(dictionary, child).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you Yacoub appreicate it , we anticipate large data set for now its 23000 records and this might grow as we add records. can  you please post solution for dictionary

Comment: @VijenderReddyChintalapudi, if this answer your question, consider marking it as an answer

Comment: @YacoubMassad your solution works perfect. However, my requirement is the opposite. I need to find all children recursively. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: @corix010, it is really hard to answer this in the comments. Try to do it yourself and if you fail, ask a question.

Comment: @YacoubMassad I tried modifying your method but could only get all descendants in one branch. Please see my question -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37441398/find-all-descendants-in-self-referencing-parent-child-hierarchical-tree

Answer (score 4):

This works:

```
var parents = elements.ToDictionary(x => x.Id, x => x.ParentId);

Func<int, IEnumerable<int?>> getParents = null;
getParents = i =>
    parents.ContainsKey(i)
        ? new [] { parents[i] }.Concat(parents[i].HasValue
            ? getParents(parents[i].Value)
            : Enumerable.Empty<int?>())
        : Enumerable.Empty<int?>();
```

If I ask for `getParents(4)` then I get this result:

[image: result]

A slightly simplified version that removes the `null` parent is this:

```
var parents =
    elements
        .Where(x => x.ParentId != null)
        .ToDictionary(x => x.Id, x => x.ParentId.Value);

Func<int, IEnumerable<int>> getParents = null;
getParents = i =>
    parents.ContainsKey(i)
        ? new [] { parents[i] }.Concat(getParents(parents[i]))
        : Enumerable.Empty<int>();
```